# ¿Como hago un Intent desde el Adapter de mi RecyclerView?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, recyclerview, android-adapter

estoy realizando un proyecto donde estoy implementando RecyclerView y FirebaseFirestore.
La cosa es asi, la comunidad me ayudo a implementar un `OnClickListener` a mi Item, pero no pude deducir como programar y hacer que funcione un `Intent` desde el `Adapter`.

```
package com.example.atipicoapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_item.view.*

class MyAdapter(private val platoList : ArrayList<Plato>,
                private val itemClickListener: OnPlatoClickListener
                ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    interface OnPlatoClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(nombre: String)
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        itemView.platoTouch.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v: View ->

                //Aca va la funcion que se activaria al presionar el Item

        })

        return MyViewHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

            val plato : Plato = platoList[position]
            holder.platoName.text = plato.platoName
            holder.platoDescription.text = plato.platoDescription
            holder.platoPrecio.text = plato.platoPrecio.toString()
            holder.platoCantidad.text = plato.platoCantidad.toString()

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return platoList.size

    }

    public class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){


        val platoName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoNombre)
        val platoDescription : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoDescripcion)
        val platoPrecio : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoPrecio)
        val platoCantidad : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoCant)

    }
}
```

Este es mi `Adapter`, yo debo escribir un `intent` y sumarle un `putExtra` que seria el nombre del plato (platoName, viene desde Firebase Firestore). No se si es posible hacerlo desde el Adapter o tengo que hacerlo desde el `Activity`, en ese caso, ¿como lo puedo hacer desde el Activity?.

Desde ya, Muchas Gracias!!

P/D Este de aqui es mi Activity que contiene el RecyclerView

```
package com.example.atipicoapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.firestore.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_menu_atipico.*

class MenuAtipicoActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyAdapter.OnPlatoClickListener {

    private lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var platoArrayList : ArrayList<Plato>
    private lateinit var myAdapter : MyAdapter
    private lateinit var db : FirebaseFirestore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_atipico)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        platoArrayList = arrayListOf()

        myAdapter = MyAdapter(platoArrayList, this)

        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter

        EventChangeListener()

        Setup()

    }

    private fun EventChangeListener(){


        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("Platos").
                addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
                    override fun onEvent(
                        value: QuerySnapshot?,
                        error: FirebaseFirestoreException?
                    ) {

                        if (error != null){

                            Log.e("Firestore Error", error.message.toString())
                            return

                        }

                        for(dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){

                           if(dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                               platoArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(Plato::class.java))

                           }

                        }

                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    }


                })


    }

    private fun Setup(){

        botonAceptar.setOnClickListener{

            val SlotIntent = Intent(this, SlotActivity::class.java).apply{



            }
            startActivity(SlotIntent)
        }

        }

    override fun onItemClick(nombre: String) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Funciono", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }



}
```

Estoy usando Kotlin

ACTUALIZACION

MyAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.atipicoapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_item.view.*

class MyAdapter(private val platoList : ArrayList<Plato>,
                private val itemClickListener: OnPlatoClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    interface OnPlatoClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(nombre: String)
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        itemView.platoTouch.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v: View ->

            //Aca va la funcion que se activaria al presionar el Item

        })

        return MyViewHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val plato : Plato = platoList[position]
        holder.platoName.text = plato.platoName
        holder.platoDescription.text = plato.platoDescription
        holder.platoPrecio.text = plato.platoPrecio.toString()
        holder.platoCantidad.text = plato.platoCantidad.toString()

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return platoList.size

    }

    public class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){


        val platoName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoNombre)
        val platoDescription : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoDescripcion)
        val platoPrecio : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoPrecio)

        val platoCantidad : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoCant)
        
        //Error 'Function declaration must have a name' y 'Expecting member declaration'
        platoCantidad.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            //Define Intent para abrir una Activity
            val intent = Intent(itemView.getContext(),SlotActivity::class.java)
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent)
        })


    }
}
```

Me salta el error `Function declaration must have a name` en la linea 64 donde empiezo a escribir en `setOnClickListener`

Gracias por su ayuda <3.

Comment: Hola, Lucas, que acción deseas realizar con el Intent, abrir una Activity?

Comment: Si, quiero abrir otra activity llamada SlotActivity, y llevarme un putExtra ( que seria platoName del Item que se clickeo)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba en el `onItemClick` crear un Intent y pásale en un putExtra el nombre del plato que obtiene la función `onItemClick`

Comment: Podrias ser un poco mas especifico, soy nuevo en RecyclerView, Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu clase "Holder" lo puedes realizar, ya que necesitas el contexto de la vista para poder realizar el Intent, este es un ejemplo:

```
public class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){


        val platoName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoNombre)
        val platoDescription : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoDescripcion)
        val platoPrecio : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoPrecio)
        
        val platoCantidad : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoCant)

        platoCantidad.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                //Define Intent para abrir una Activity
                val intent = Intent(itemView.getContext(),OtraActivity::class.java)
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent)
            })

    }
```

Comment: Al escribir el código como lo muestras en el ejemplo me salta el error `Expecting member declaration`

Comment: Escribe que variable es la que muestra el error, recuerda que puse OtraActivity como una Activity de ejemplo, cual es la que deseas abrir?

Comment: El error me empieza a saltar en la linea 64, que es la linea en donde empiezo a escribir `platoCantidad.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            //Define Intent para abrir una Activity
            val intent = Intent(itemView.getContext(),SlotActivity::class.java)
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent)
        })`     Si cambie el nombre del Activity al que corresponde a mi proyecto

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta, agregando abajo todo el método por favor.

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta, espero que te sea util para ayudarme. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Logre Solucionar mi problema agregando una funcion bind a mi MyViewHolder y luego llamandola desde el OnBindViewHolder.

Mi codigo quedo asi:

```
package com.example.atipicoapp

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_item.view.*

class MyAdapter(private val platoList : ArrayList<Plato>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {






    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {

        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        itemView.platoTouch.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v: View ->


        })

        return MyViewHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val plato: Plato = platoList[position]
        holder.platoName.text = plato.platoName
        holder.platoDescription.text = plato.platoDescription
        holder.platoPrecio.text = plato.platoPrecio.toString()
        holder.platoCantidad.text = plato.platoCantidad.toString()

        when(holder){

            is MyViewHolder -> {

                holder.bind(platoList[position])

            }

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return platoList.size

    }

    public class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        val platoName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoNombre)
        val platoDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoDescripcion)
        val platoPrecio: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoPrecio)

        val platoTouch: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoTouch)

        val platoCantidad: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoCant)



        private val mActivity = itemView.context as Activity
        private val intent = Intent(mActivity,SlotActivity::class.java)


        fun bind(plato: Plato){

            platoTouch.setOnClickListener{


                intent.putExtra("id", platoName.text.toString())
                mActivity.startActivity(intent)
            }

        }


    }
}
```